# Фильтрация трафика через Cubietruck

Tags: сеть, embedded

Имеется роутер *D-Link DIR-825 Rev.D1*.

На хабре увидел статью про фильтрацию трафика через роутер и захотелось сделать нечто подобное, но был разочарован, что поддерживаются только стоковые прошивки.

В наличии также имеется *Cubietruck*, воткнутый через *LAN*.

Есть ли возможность производить фильтрацию через него?

Comment: Поясните - что конкретно хотите сделать?
Как вариант - можно поискать альтернативные прошивки к роутеру...

Answer (score 1):

если устройство оснащено хотя бы двумя сетевыми интерфейсами (*ethernet*, *wifi*, *bluetooth* и пр.), то — да, можно фильтровать трафик, проходящий через устройство между двумя сетевыми интерфейсами.

если же сетевой интерфейс всего один — то, теоретически, возможно, но, во-первых, настройка значительно усложняется, во-вторых, такое использование несёт в себе, как мне представляется, весьма мало смысла.